# javascript cicle for duplicated values with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Hello guys i'm struggling with this problem.

I have html select with options and a input field to receive the values of the selected options.

So i have a script with FOR to get the options selected, in that input field.

The issue is that in the FOR cicle it writtes repeated values.

In the link posted you will see the problem.

[This is the website for testing want i have](https://ruisonika.pt/site_antigo/_pitch/pahldata/dashboard/select2.html)

This is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
  allowClear: true
});

function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
  var opts = [],
    opt;
  var len = sel.options.length;
  var input = document.getElementById("inputId1");
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      input.value += opt.value + ",";
      //alert(opt.value);
    }
  }
  //return opts;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row space-top">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <select id="selectedOptions" class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="colaboradores[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:100% !important;" onchange="getSelectedOptions(this)">
        <option value="U1">User 1</option>
        <option value="U2">User 2</option>
        <option value="U3">User 3</option>
        <option value="G1">Grupo 1</option>
        <option value="G2">Grupo 2</option>
        <option value="G3">Grupo 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row space-top">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputId1">Valores recebidos do select 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId1" aria-describedby="peqDesc">
        <small id="peqDesc" class="form-text text-muted">Estas são as variáveis que recebo do select 2</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty the input with `input.value = ''` before the for loop before rewriting the values :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});

function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
  var opts = [],
    opt;
  var len = sel.options.length;
  var input = document.getElementById("inputId1");
  input.value = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      input.value += opt.value + ",";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row space-top">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <select id="selectedOptions" class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="colaboradores[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:100% !important;" onchange="getSelectedOptions(this)">
        <option value="U1">User 1</option>
        <option value="U2">User 2</option>
        <option value="U3">User 3</option>
        <option value="G1">Grupo 1</option>
        <option value="G2">Grupo 2</option>
        <option value="G3">Grupo 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row space-top">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputId1">Valores recebidos do select 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId1" aria-describedby="peqDesc">
        <small id="peqDesc" class="form-text text-muted">Estas são as variáveis que recebo do select 2</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Islam Elshobokshy that it!
so near and i missed

Comment: Happy to help @rui_sonika :-)